# Fedora GUI software update inconsistent with dnf command line update

Tags: fedora, gnome, dnf

During a Gnome session I received an upgrade notification from Software Update so I switched to a tty (I never run 'dnf upgrade' inside an X session) to run the update but 'dnf upgrade' shows that no updates are available.
The Software Update gui clearly shows a higher version for the new packages but a 'dnf list updates' does not display them.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is the gui tool using different repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, the GUI tool and DNF use different caches. This is being worked on but is a known annoyance. They will eventually come into sync. You can use `dnf --refresh` to force DNF to update its cache.

Comment: Has this been resolved in the time since the answer was posted?

Comment: Perfect timing — this should be resolved in F29 beta, released today.